# comparing array subscripts in LLVM

Tags: llvm

I am analyzing getelementptr instructions for array accesses. How can I compare the subscripts for two gep instructions with array accesses?

For example, for the code

```
a[i]=b[i+1]+i;
```

How can I compare two array subscripts `i` and `i+1` in IR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over them using [GetElementPtrInst::idx_begin()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html#aceaa5a2bd964e34d0dbf3ed1f146abc7) function.